# How to use data from one component in another component vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I'm new to vue and I'm trying to use an array from one component to another but I cannot find how to do it.

In component 1 I have this data that I want to transfer and use in component 2.

```
   const array = [];
```

In app.vue I have these 2 components next to eachother.

```
<template>
  <Component 1/>
  <Component 2 />
</template>
```

Now how do I get this array from component 1 to component 2?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Through a common parent. Probably it should contain the state and not a child

Comment: This is such a common problem that it has its own name: Lifting state up. Typically, you'd do this by moving the state to the nearest common ancestor (parent) of the components you want to share state between

Comment: Sometimes, however, this isn't ideal. In those cases, people often reach for global state managers like `vuex`/`pinia` or `mobx`

Comment: @DerekPollard you don't need a state manager to share data between instances, we have been doing such a thing way before state managers became a thing. You just need a global object initialized at startup. This object is the application itself.

Comment: @EricMORAND that's cool, but ultimately irrelevant given the context of the question

Comment: That's an interesting stance considering you are the one who mentioned state managers. Anyway: data that don't belong to any component belongs to the global context - the application. Reminding this reality is not irrelevant in my opinion. It should even be the answer, actually.

Comment: State managers were mentioned as an alternative, and rightly so; they should be part of this dialog. Also, it's likely the nearest common ancestor to OP's "app.vue" is... "the app". Seems like everyone here is saying the same thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Vue SFC Playground](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)

As mentioned in the question's comments you should move your array outside `Component1` and share it between the both components.

But if you strongly want/need/have to keep your array inside `Component1` you can share the array through a scoped slot that put in the end of `Component1`:

App.vue

```
<script setup>
import Component1 from './Component1.vue';
import Component2 from './Component2.vue';
</script>

<template>
  <Component1>
    <template #="{array}">
      <Component2 :array="array" />
    </template>
  </Component1>
</template>
```

Component1.vue

```
<script setup>
import {ref, shallowReactive} from 'vue';
const array = shallowReactive(['item1', 'item2']);
const itemId = ref(array.length);
</script>

<template>
  <div>I'm Component1</div>
  <button @click="array.push(`item${++itemId}`)">Add item to list</button>
  <slot v-bind="{array}"/>
</template>
```

Component2.vue

```
<script setup>
defineProps({
  array:{type:Array, default: []}
});
</script>
<template>
  <div>I'm Component2</div>
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in array">{{item}}</li>
  </ul>
</template>
```